# C'est le moment

Tags: choix-de-mot

Pourquoi dit-on

> c'est le moment où

Et non pas

> c'est le moment quand
>   ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Où n'est pas seulement un adverbe de lieu, c'est aussi un adverbe de temps.

Cela correspond à une vision spatiale du temps (le temps comme sur une frise chronologique par exemple), on parle bien de l'espace-temps...

En fait, il y a une autre explication, plus grammaticale, qui tient à la nature grammaticale de ces 2 mots.

"Quand" est une conjonction. Il relie 2 propositions (bouts de phrases qui pourraient être des phrases autonomes, car elles ont un sujet, un verbe.)
Ex: "*Je te le donnerai **quand** tu le mériteras*"

Il n'a pas que cette fonction, il peut aussi être utilisé comme adverbe interrogatif. 
Ex: "*Quand seras-tu prête ?*"

On dit aussi: "*Tu pars quand ?*" Mais c'est la même chose que "*Quand est-ce que tu pars ?*"

"Où" est l'adverbe de lieu, et de temps.

Donc, on ne traduira pas toujours l'anglais "when" par "quand", mais quelques fois, selon le contexte, par "où" !